# why I got 'strict-dynamic' is present?

Tags: content-security-policy

I want to create CSP for my site and I used CSP mitigator extension in the Chrome browser

My app was written with Elixir and phoenix-framework and I use nginx for the web server

nginx headers are:

```
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

I've written many rules for CSP such as:

```
default-src 'none'; 
base-uri 'none';
form-action 'none'; 
frame-ancestors 'none'; 
script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://example.com https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com https://www.google-analytics.com 'nonce-hZwUTOrpRdsdlZmODf631g==';
style-src 'self'  'nonce-hZwUTOrpRdsdlZmODf631g==' https://example.com 'unsafe-inline' https://www.googletagmanager.com   https://fonts.googleapis.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha;
img-src  'self' https://example.com:443 https://ssl.gstatic.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://www.google-analytics.com;
frame-src https://www.gstatic.com https://www.google.comhttps://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html;
font-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://example.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;
connect-src www.google-analytics.com  https://www.google-analytics.com  https://stats.g.doubleclick.net ;
object-src 'none';
report-uri https://my_code.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly;
```

and continuously my console has errors:
https://gist.github.com/mojtaba-naserei/da75abac20c94a655dd2ab2e652dab8d

=============================

My questions are:

1) Why did I receive

> 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based whitelisting is disabled

when I never define `'strict-dynamic'` in my CSP?

2) Why do I get this error:

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the image 'https://example.com/images/smal-trangell-logo.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' data: filesystem: blob: ws: wss: ". 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based whitelisting is disabled. Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

when I defined a rule for this: `img-src 'self' https://example.com:443`?

Comment: What happens if you try testing with the extension disabled? There's also the subject of the [CSP 3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#strict-dynamic-usage) which is where `strict-dynamic` is introduced, and it seems that `nonce`s are specifically tied to using `strict-dynamic`. However, it looks like `strict-dynamic` *has* to be defined. Maybe your browser or extension is adding `strict-dynamic` to accommodate your `nonce` attribute under `script-src`?

Comment: thanks for the response. my problem was solved when I moved my code from local to the server . and I don't use report mode. every time I see a blocked message, next I add a rule to CSP and errors are gone

Comment: That's the way to do it. :) I used report-only mode for around six months before I was ready to go live with my CSP, but it varies depending on the site and traffic.